# auto checking of table values at every month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i need to change values of a column in a table automatically at the end of every month,like say i ve a number of students joined for a course..the students status should change after their course period from studying to completed automatically in the database.

The whole table should be checking for this criteria every month.what should i use triggers? is there any other way? i am using mysql.Thank You

Comment: You need to create cron job.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: Just store the course completion (or course commencement and duration)